# Attribute Error or Simplifying Code?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, attributes

I am trying to run this code.

```
class CalcGPA:

    def __init__(self):
        self.g1 = float(input("Please enter grade 1: "))
        self.g2 = float(input("Please enter grade 2: "))
        self.g3 = float(input("Please enter grade 3: "))
        self.g4 = float(input("Please enter grade 4: "))
        self.ap = float(input("Please enter total AP classes: "))
        self.hn = float(input("Please enter total Honors classes: "))
        self.weight = self.ap + (self.hn * 0.5)
        self.grades_list = [self.g1, self.g2, self.g3, self.g4]
        self.gpa_list = []
        self.gpa = 0

def conv_grades(self):
    for i in self.grades_list:
        if i >= 90:
            self.gpa_list.append(4)
        elif 80 <= i <= 89:
            self.gpa_list.append(3)
        elif 70 <= i <= 79:
            self.gpa_list.append(2)
        elif 60 <= i <= 69:
            self.gpa_list.append(1)
        else :
            self.gpa_list.append(0)

    self.gpa = (sum(self.gpa_list) + self.weight) / len(self.gpa_list)

def show_gpa(self):
    print("Your current GPA as calculated is: {}".format(self.gpa))
```

I start with `python3` then `import gpaCalc`. Next is,

`student_1 = gpaCalc.CalcGPA()`.

But, after I type the grades and classes in then type

```
student_1.conv_grades()
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError: CalcGPA instance has no attribute 'conv_grades'
```

Is there some type of way I can fix this error? Even better would be a way I could run all of this just by typing `python3 gpaCalc.py`? Then I could make it really simple and be able to run it all in one line through the terminal. Thanks!

Comment: You haven't indented the function `conv_grades` correctly and python is interpreting it as a `function`, not a `method`. Indent both function definitions to be able to access them through the instance `student_1`.

Comment: Okay but now when I run show_gpa it is bounding the method and I cant get it to print